# iOS- How to break down a web content and display it as you want

Tags: ios, web-applications

I've been wondering how all the web apps display web content, say on a UITableView. When we call UIWebView instance method loadRequest: it simply surfs away to the link provided with the NSURL object. But how do we further manage all the contents with TableViews, ImageViews and so on. What is the basic principle of web apps in iOS? Do I need to learn HTML and any other web related technology like AJAX,java script etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't display the contents of a `UIWebView` in a `UITableView` (or `UIImageView`, etc.) The apps you're likely referring to use one of two approaches:

- Download the data using `NSURLConnection`, usually with REST and JSON. Then display it in a `UITableView`.
- Display HTML content in a `UIWebView` that looks like a `UITableView`

For more information on the first case see the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html). For more information on the second case, see [Getting Started with iOS Web Apps](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneWebApp/_index.html).

Most things that could run in MobileSafari can also run in a `UIWebView`. It is difficult, however, to get native, correct behavior for all your UI elements using a `UIWebView`. [Button taps in particular do not work correctly in most web apps.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898477/proper-touch-button-behavior-for-mobilesafari) Swipes also can behave non-optimally. But even so, many "apps" out there are actually just web pages in a `UIWebView`. (The Facebook app is a good example of this.)

Comment: Rob, regarding your comment on button taps not working correctly, is it customary to avoid using Javascript with UIWebView?

Comment: No. JavaScript is fairly common in UIWebView. It's a flakey and difficult way to program, but it's fairly common. I certainly don't know of much effort to *avoid* JS in UIWebView.

Comment: Based on your experience, do you think it's more reliable, and better programming practice, to use the first option you discussed where JSON/XML is downloaded to the app while using native display elements, such as UITableView, to render the content?